# How to fix "cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object" error when using torch.multiprocessing.spawn

Tags: python, deep-learning, python-multiprocessing, torch

I am training some PyTorch model on a Linux machine with 2 Tesla M60 GPUs and am using this example for splitting the training across the two GPUs using data parallelisation https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-scale-training-on-multiple-gpus-dae1041f49d2

However, when the code gets to the point of calling the torch.multiprocessing.spawn function, it raises the

> TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object

I know it would be best practice to post a small reproducible example, however the codebase is very large, and I've been unable to reproduce this error on a small enough model to be posted here. The python error traceback also doesn't help much as it just refers to the internals of the multiprocessing library. I know this may sound a bit too general without a code sample, but I was just wondering if someone has encountered this same error when multiprocessing with PyTorch on a Linux machine, and if so, what are the things to look out for to try and fix it. Code runs absolutely fine on a single GPU, so it's proving very hard to debug.

If it helps, I'm using python 3.8.11 and torch 1.9.0, CUDA version 11.1

Comment: Hi, I've now done some further debugging and ablation tests in my code, and I've found what's causing the error. I was using the tensorflow's SummaryWriter available  from torch.utils.tensorboard and for some reasons the torch multiprocessing doesn't like that. After removing the SummaryWriter from the training loop, everything works fine. Not sure if this is a bug or why it's happening, but I'll leave the question here in case it can help anyone else.